# "Спасибо" -- с восклицательным знаком или без?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли считать грамотным употребление слова "спасибо" без восклицательного знака (нередко встречается в сети)?

Comment: "Спасибо" может употребляться и как существительное...  Или Вы спрашиваете об употреблении его самого по себе?

Comment: Я имею в виду его употребление как слова, выражающего благодарность кого-либо к кому-либо.

Comment: Матвей, +1000 за вопрос! Я так же воспринимаю и мог бы задать такой же вопрос тут, если бы зарегистрировался раньше и пришло бы в голову это. Сам с трудом могу после фразы со "спасибо" поставить точку, а после просто "спасибо" вообще никогда не поставлю, лучше вообще не буду благодарить. Даже "привет" и "пока" пишу либо с "!", либо просто без знаков где-то в чате, хотя часто и там с "!". А "здравствуйте" (на Вы) тем более чаще с "!" у меня, если не всегда. Бывает только я избегаю "!" по каким-то причинам и пишу: "Здравствуйте, (имя), я тут...". Но так редко.

Comment: Рад пониманию, Артём. И мне тоже трудно писать "привет, пока, спасибо" без восклицательного знака.

Comment: Заглунул сюда и не могу понять, за что удалили ответ Tagirix-а.((

Comment: Наверное, ему нужно было дать ссылку на формальное правило, как это сделал Серж, а Tagirix дал ответ-ИМХО.

Comment: И я считаю, что дал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае употребление восклицательного знака является факультативным. Подробно об употреблении восклицательного знака Вы можете прочитать здесь. 
[Раздел 1. Знаки препинания в конце предложения и при перерыве речи  »»   § 3. Восклицательный знак](http://orthographia.ru/go.php?url=http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=89#pp89) Розенталь.Д.Э.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и дельную ссылку, Серж !